# Show that $ P(A_n) = 1 \forall n \Leftrightarrow P( \bigcap A_n) =1 $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ (\Omega,F,P) $ be a probability space and $ A_1,A_2,... \in F $.Show that

$ P(A_n)= \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow P( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) =1  $

My idea:

$ "\Rightarrow:" $
$ Let P(A_n)=1 \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}. $ I know that:

$ P(A_n)+P(A_n^C)=1 \, \Rightarrow P(A_n^C)=0 $

Then: $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n^C) = 0 $ and we get that $  ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n^C ))^C = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n) =1 $

$ "\Leftarrow:" Let P(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=1. $ Then:

$ P(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = 1- P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^C) = 1- \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n^C) =1 $

$ \Rightarrow P(A_n^C)=0 \Rightarrow P(A_n)=1 $

Is my proof correct? or does someone have a better idea to proof this?

Comment: There are some flaws. For example, you cannot assume no overlap in the complements. You are only allowed to use sigma-subaddivity for this sequence. As a hint, look this concept up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cup P(A_n^{c})$ has no meaning. Union is for sets, not for numbers.

$P(A_n)=1$ for all $n$ implies $P(A_n^{c})=0$ for all $n$ and this implies $P(\cup _n A_n^{c}) \leq \sum P(A_n^{c})=0$ so $P(\cap_n A_n)=1$. Converse follows immediately from the fact that $\cap_n A_n\subset A_k$ for each $k$.

Comment: Thank you, I understood.